# Functional form of fluorescent light flicker in time

Tags: electric-current, fluorescence

I will start with the disclaimer that I am a mathematician and do not know much about physics.

I am interested in modeling light emitted from fluorescent bulbs and am curious about the relative intensity of these light sources as a function of time.  I know there is *flicker* (intensity modulations) that occur from the alternating current passing through the bulb.  Is the intensity versus time appropriately modeled by a sinusoidal function, e.g. $\sin^2(\omega t)$?  Has there been any formal studies that model the functional form of the output intensity of these light sources with time?

Comment: For an ordinary compact fluorescent lamp, powered by AC line voltage, the light intensity has various fluctuations on top of the large DC component. The fluctuations occur at various multiples of the line frequency and a simple sine wave model is too simple. Fluorescent lamps and their noises are the bane of those of us who spent many hours in very dark rooms trying to do sensitive laser spectroscopy.

Comment: A power line power spectrum is shown here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/363374/223146. The fluorescent lamp complicates things further since the lamp’s fluorescent and phosphorescent coatings “filter” the temporal behavior of the white light output. And [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/164168/79678), the tenth figure shows my spectrum of a compact fluorescent lamp.